# Misma columna en tablas relacionadas con valores distintos en base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, tablas

Estoy intentando hacer una práctica que consiste en hacer varias listas de la compra, para varios días diferentes, y dentro de cada lista hay una serie de productos.

He pensado que tendría que hacer una tabla con las diferentes listas de la compra, una tabla con todos los productos que se puedan añadir a esa lista de la compra (no quiero que se escriban campos nuevos, quiero sólo que se puedan elegir los disponibles en esa tabla) y una tabla intermedia en la que entiendo que habría una columna con filas con el id de la lista de la compra y el id de cada producto, ya que diferentes listas pueden tener productos comunes, como arroz o leche.

La cuestión es que ahora tengo una duda, porque quiero que cada producto tenga un checkbox con comprado / no comprado y un valor con la cantidad que se quiere comprar, 3, 10 o 100. El problema surge en que si esos elementos son comunes, al editar el valor de un "comprado/no comprado" o una cantidad en un producto, esas cantidades o checks cambiarían en todas las demás listas, y no es lo que quiero, quiero que cada producto tenga su cantidad y su check diferente en cada lista.

¿Tendría entonces que hacer sólo dos tablas, una con las listas, y otra con productos que puedan tener el nombre repetido, y una columna en la tabla de productos con el id de la lista a la que está asociado cada producto? ¿Cuál sería la solución más óptima?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es usar esa entidad intermedia entre ellas.

Tienes la entidad producto y la entidad lista, entre estas dos entidades se genera una relación de muchos a muchos ya que un producto puede estar en muchas listas y una lista puede tener muchos productos, quedando la nueva entidad (tabla) que la puedes llamar listas_productos, es en esta entidad que vas a tener esos datos que comentas debido a que son datos que nacen de la relación entre lista y producto.

Quería así:

```
Lista
ID | Fecha
 1 | 01-01-2019

Producto
ID | Nombre
  1| Camisa

 Listas_productos
 ID_lista | ID_producto | comprado | cantidad
         1|            1|   false  |        5
```